# How to pass an expression to a method when the variables in the expression are inside the scope of the method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, lambda, dry, argument-passing

I must be missing some fundamentals of lambdas and delegates. Here it goes..

I have two functions which does "nearly" identical things. I need to OOP them by writing them to one function and passing the "necessary" arguments.

The two functions roughly look like this:

```
private static bool Populate1(int yPoint)
{
    //---------------------------------
    //--------------------------------
    int xPoint = 0;

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        ComboBox cb = AddControl_Combo(item, xPoint, yPoint);

        xPoint += cb.Width + 12;
        yPoint = 0;
    }

    //-------------------------------
    //-------------------------------

    return true;
}

private static bool Populate2(int yPoint)
{
    //---------------------------------
    //--------------------------------
    int xPoint = 0;

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        ComboBox cb = AddControl_Combo(item, xPoint, yPoint);

        yPoint += cb.Height + 12;
    }

    //---------------------------------
    //--------------------------------

    return true;
}
```

The functions are a lot more verbose, so I want to really DRY them. As one can notice, the only difference in the two functions are two positioning functions

```
xPoint += cb.Width + 12;
yPoint = 0;
```

and

```
yPoint += cb.Height + 12;
```

How can I make the above two functions into one by passing the above expressions as argument? The trouble I find is that variables `xPoint` and `cb` are variables inside the scope of the very functions!

Here is what I tried and succeeded, but not elegant in my opinion:

```
private static bool Populate(ref int xPoint, ref int yPoint, ref ComboBox cb, 
                              Action positioningFunc)
{
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        cb = AddControl_Combo(item, xPoint, yPoint);

        positioningFunc();
    }

    return true;
}
```

And call it:

```
int xPoint = 0;
int yPoint = 0;
ComboBox cb = null;
return Populate(ref xPoint, ref yPoint, ref cb, () =>
{
    xPoint += cb.Width + 12;
    yPoint = 0;
});
```

and

```
int xPoint = 0;
int yPoint = 19;
ComboBox cb = null;
return Populate(ref xPoint, ref yPoint, ref cb, () =>
{
    yPoint += cb.Height + 12;
});
```

Is there a better way to OOP them?

**Edit:** The two expressions I'm trying to pass positions some dynamic controls (horizontally, vertically, diagonally, zig zag etc). The function is already called from 4 different places and would scale. To get the expression itself we do a lot of calculation from the calling class. So doing an `if else` logic inside the `Populate` function (which is in a separate Utility class) is not what I would want. And the only change in all the methods are those positioning expressions inside the foreach. So I am looking for how arguments in this case can be passed.

Comment: Use parameters in the lambda.

Comment: You're adding some overhead (function call and reducing opportunities for local optimizations) using the lamdas.  For most code that would not matter, but if you have lots of points that could make a difference to user perception.

Comment: @SLaks I am not that good at lambda.. Can you post a sample code? I am not sure how to use parameters in lambda and later use it from the method

Comment: nawfal, you could sign two named arguments, xpoint and ypoint. Inside the method, you apply the position according to which argument you received. No Lambda required.

Comment: Forget about it, we're just talking about yPoint after all

Comment: @AndreCalil I can not do that. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need it done through Lambdas here's an alternative:

```
 private static bool Populate(int yPoint, Func<ComboBox, Point, Point> modifier)
 {
    var point = new Point (0, yPoint);
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        ComboBox cb = AddControl_Combo(item, point.X, point.Y);
        point = modifier(cb, point);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And the two calls would be:

```
Populate(0, (cb, point) => new Point(point.X + cb.Width + 12, 0));
Populate(0, (cb, point) => new Point(0, point.Y + cb.Height + 12));
```

You could also use `Tuple<int, int>` but `Point` is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

Simple logic

```
private static bool Populate(int yPoint, bool flag)
{
    int xPoint = 0;

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        var ComboBox cb = AddControl_Combo(item, xPoint, yPoint);

        if(flag)
        {
            xPoint += cb.Width + 12;
            yPoint = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            yPoint += cb.Height + 12;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

When you want Populate1, call `Populate(valueofypoint, true)` and `Populate(valueofypoint, false)` for Populate2 call.

Answer (score 1):

This should work exactly as you need:

```
private static bool Populate(int yPoint,
    Func<int, ComboBox, int> xStep,
    Func<int, ComboBox, int> yStep)
{
    int xPoint = 0;

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        ComboBox cb = AddControl_Combo(item, xPoint, yPoint);

        xPoint = xStep(xPoint, cb);
        yPoint = yStep(xPoint, cb);
    }

    return true;
}
```

You just call it like so:

```
Populate(42, (x, cb) => x + cb.Width + 12, (y, cb) => 0);
Populate(42, (x, cb) => 0, (y, cb) => y + cb.Width + 12);
```

Is this what you're expecting?

Comment: Simpler. Like this. But I find @Pablo Romeo's answer easier to call.

Answer (score 0):

Combining your idea and Nikhil suggestion:

```
private static bool Populate(int yPoint, int position)
{
    int xPoint = 0;

    ComboBox cb;

    Action positionFunction;
    if (position == 1)
    {
            positionFunction = () => { 
                    xPoint += cb.Width + 12;
                    yPoint = 0;
            };
    }
    else if (position ==2)
    {
            positionFunction = () => { yPoint += cb.Height + 12; };
    }
    else
    {
            throw new Exception("Invalid position");
    }

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        cb = AddControl_Combo(item, xPoint, yPoint);

        positionFunction();
    }

    return true;
}
```